# Call methods of a number literal

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can call `str` methods on string literal. But I cannot call `int` methods on a integer number literal:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
>>> 1.bit_length()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1.bit_length()
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> a = 1
>>> a.bit_length()
1
>>> ', '.join(['1', '2'])
'1, 2'
>>>
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python treats `1.` as a beginning of a float number, but fails to parse the rest of the line. Change it to

```
(1).bit_length()
```

by enclosing the number literal with parenthesis, we make sure that python evaluates the expression within the parens, which is `1` and call the method on that number.

Python defines [floating point literal](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals) like this

```
floatnumber   ::=  pointfloat | exponentfloat
pointfloat    ::=  [intpart] fraction | intpart "."
exponentfloat ::=  (intpart | pointfloat) exponent
intpart       ::=  digit+
fraction      ::=  "." digit+
exponent      ::=  ("e" | "E") ["+" | "-"] digit+
```

As per that definition, the lexical analyzer thinks that `1.bit_length()` would be a float literal, since `1.` matches the `[intpart] fraction`'s beginning. But the rest of the line doesn't match. That is why it fails.

Comment: ```1 .bit_length()``` should also work, but it's ugly.

Comment: How does Ruby handle `3.times`?